# Responsive issue; text renders incorrect size until orientation changes?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, responsive-design, viewport

I'm experiencing something rather odd, in that [this page](http://www.yousefsoliman.com/xforsmb/)
renders the text incorrectly sized on initial load, however when the orientation is changed from portrait to landscape and back again it renders fine.

I've tried adding in various properties for the `viewport` meta tag, however, this doesn't seem to have any effect.

My current `viewport` meta tag has the following properties;

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

This behaviour happens on iPhone (5S; iOS7), haven't tested across any other devices. I'm really puzzled as to what the source of the issue could be?

If anyone could suggest any additional `viewport` properties or other ideas on how this may be fixed it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to note; `#intro` which is the top section of the page loads absolutely fine, however I can't figure out what the difference is between that section and the others in terms of the way font-sizing is set (all use `em` units) with `<body>` as the base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this into your css:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
```

Comment: Awesome, worked! Will accept when timer is out - thanks a lot.